# Не работает cron

Tags: php, cron

Была задача - выполнять php-скрипт по cron раз в минуту. Но cron почему-то не работает. В логи пишет, что выполняет, а на самом деле ничего не происходит.

cron-задача:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/pingcheck/pingcheck.ru/public_html/statistics/ping.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Лог:

```
Aug 31 12:03:01 localhost CRON[30532]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /home/pingcheck/pingcheck.ru/public_html/statistics/ping.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А на основании чего Вы делаете вывод, что скрипт не выполняется? Уберите перенаправление вывода и посмотрите, что придет на e-mail администратора. Вполне вероятно, ошибка в Вашем скрипте.

Comment: А что должно происходить? :) Вы проверяли работе скрипта в окружении, формируемом CRON-ом?

Comment: Запустите самостоятельно скрипт в CLI и посмотрите output. Либо ищите error_log. Убедитесь, что скрипт сам по себе действительно работает, а потом уже грешите на крон.

Comment: cron выполняет скрипт, который производит запись в текстовый файл. Я сделал вывод, что cron не работает, потому что не производится запись в этот самый текстовик.Сам по себе скрипт работает, и запись в файл производит.

Comment: Проблема всё ещё актуальна.

Answer (score 1):

проблема, вероятно, в том, что скрипту «чего-то не хватает».

попробуйте не отправлять вывод скрипта «в топку», а сохранить его в файл. например, так:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/pingcheck/pingcheck.ru/public_html/statistics/ping.php >>/tmp/somefile 2>&1
```

тогда в `/tmp/somefile` попадёт всё, что выдаст программа *php* при попытке интерпретации вашего скрипта. ищите там сообщения об ошибках.